# How to group an array by its parent_id? (php / laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently assigned to task in which I will need to group raw array data. The data is very simple and it has `root_id` to determine the parent of the element. The task is to group it dynamically based from DB data.

Now, I already tried constructing draft flowchart but I always end up problematic for nested child. I would kindly ask of your help, how to make this possible in PHP or Laravel in a good performance way.

Below in the left, is the raw data array and the right side is the expected grouped array-object.

[image]

```js
$data = [
    {
        id: 1
        root: null
    },
    {
        id: 2
        root: null
    },
    {
        id: 3
        root: 1
    },
    {
        id: 4
        root: 2
    },
    {
        id: 5
        root: 3
    },
    {
        id: 6
        root: 5
    },
];


$expectedGroupResult = [
    {
        id: 1
        root: null
        child: [
            {
                id: 3,
                root: 1
                child: [
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        root: 3,
                        child: [
                            {
                                id: 6,
                                root: 5,
                                child: [],
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        root: null,
        child: [
            {
                id: 4,
                root: 2,
                child: []
            },
        ],
    }
];
```

Comment: Recursion is your friend

Comment: @Justinas marked answer not working. it displays one parent element only. the `id: 2` is missing. The other answers not working at all.

Comment: @Justinas i did some adjustments. now working perfectly.